# IE8 z-index glitch - cant seem to find a working solution

Tags: internet-explorer-8, z-index

I have tried all the suggestions on here I just can't seem to get mine to pop-up in front of my stylesheet in IE.  Works in firefox and chrome.  Here is a very basic example of my layout.

the website is gulfstreamdata dot com .  If you add anything to the cart and then in the top-right click on "expand" it drops down whats in your cart, but in IE it pops-under the template. :(

```
<div class="vmCartModule" style="position:relative; z-index:900; ">

<div id="dropdown" style="position:absolute; z-index:901;">

</div>

</div>
```

I tried making both z-index values the same and i tried making the outer div higher.  Tried about everything I could think of in IE developer tools to no avail.

Comment: Sorry but with mine IE8 that expand and cart menu appears on bottom page...

Comment: Really?  Thats interesting, I havent been able to recreate that on multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway since it is positioned in a position you know, maybe you could detach it from the parent div, and move it after its actual parent div, so it will be drawn on front (also removing the z-index values).

```
<div class="vmCartModule">

</div>

<div id="dropdown" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">

</div>
```

you shouldn't have problems in positioning it relative to the body, since it's on top right of the site.

**EDIT**

If it pops under your template, move that div to the bottom of your website, maybe right before `</body>`. I had the same issue with many menu and sub menus and it always worked perfectly.

Comment: Edited with code cause I forgot to style the code and it wasn't shown.

Comment: I can't exactly move the div to the bottom of the page bc it is loaded in a module during page load and is nested in some if statements...

Comment: If it's loaded as a module it means you are using javascript I presume. If that's the case you can simply append it somewhere else using JS.

Comment: its only using javascript to change the style.display of the div.  I didnt really want to have to try and append the div to a different area of the page.  That seems like quite a bit of non-sense for this. stupid IE!!

Comment: Just set position:absolute; to that div and you will be able to move it whenever you want, then give it a z-index very high, like 999999.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<div id="dropdown" style="position:absolute; z-index:901;">
    //your content
</div>
<div class="vmCartModule" style="position:relative; z-index:900; ">
    //your content
</div>
```

See demo in IE8 : http://jsfiddle.net/WtWqX/8/

Comment: Maybe I explained this wrong.  I dont need to to expand over the parent div. but it is going to drop down over a div that comes after this code.